# What factors contribute to position shown in assisting kills

Tags: league-of-legends

When you earn an assist with at least three teamates theres the killer and the people who assisted in the kill,positioned on the side. What factors contribute to the positioning of assists closest to the teamate that scored the kill's icon?.

Comment: Is there a particular problem this question is supposed to solve for you? or are you just asking out of curiosity?

Comment: @ColinD out of curiosity

Comment: I've always assumed it was whoever dealt the most dmg\healed the most\sheilded the most, however the game compares these actions. Never put much thought into it, good question.

Comment: Nice Question, I would assume it would be whoever damages/heals/shields last before the enemy gets killed and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I don't misunderstand your question (my english isn't the best) but I think the order of the assist display is dependant on what MMR/Pickorder you had at the start of the game or at least the display order of the champions ingame.

As you can see [here](http://www.pcgamesn.com/sites/default/files/LoL%20s2%20semis%20-%20CLG%20v%20AZF%20-%20Game%201%20-%20bottom%20teamfight.jpg) Alistar and Karthus always appear next to eachother.
 And i hardly doubt that alistar did more damage than a karthus and it would be really strange if they allowed shielding/movementspeedbuffs to gain assists but made the order dependant of damage dealt to the champion.

Also [here](http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/WcTWVgnwo30/maxresdefault.jpg) you can see the order of purple team on the right and the assist display. 
You may notice how the killer is (what a surprise) always the big icon, while the champions that assisted are in their order displayed on the right.

I have no detailed information about how the ingame display order in normal games is created but in ranked games it's determined by the mmr (not the division) so I assume in normal it's the W/L ratio of your normal games.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe the first one to hit them or heal/shield the allied champion will come secondly. The one that actually gets the killing blow will be in the front, and so on. So if I auto attack, then our Soraka does, then Rengar picks up the kill, it will be:

Rengar->(Me)->Soraka

Comment: Isn't the killer all the way to the right?

Comment: Yep, the killer is on the left of the far right, having a trio of swords point at the victim with like a "swipe" image.

Answer (score -5):

1) Spells/Basic Attack on the enemy 
or

2) healing/shielding to ally who has dealt damage to the enemy.

Comment: sorry i kinda want to know how each form of assist type compares with another.